# How to use _.each with an object or multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array, underscore.js

I'm developing a small app for a tournament and i'm learning underscorejs , but do not understand the use of _.each...
For each team there are 5 players , but here I only put 2 players

```
var partita = 
{

    squadra_A:
    {

        giocatore_74:
        {
        nome:'Marco',
        numero:8,
        ruolo:'playmaker'
        },
        giocatore_65:
        {
        nome:'Alessandro',
        numero:4,
        ruolo:'guardia'
        }

    },
    squadra_B:
    {

        giocatore_87:
        {
        nome:'Carlo',
        numero:5,
        ruolo:'playmaker'
        },
        giocatore_98:
        {
        nome:'Alessio',
        numero:4,
        ruolo:'ala piccola'
        }

    }

}; 

_.each(partita, function(value, key,list)
{
    //I would like to print to video the two teams with the properties of all 10 players
});
```

Comment: looks like an multilayer object..

Comment: however, whats the problem?

Comment: I do not know how to show the players in _.each function

Comment: you need two `_.each`, see my answer

Answer (score 3):

should be self explainable

```js
var partita = {
    squadra_A: {
        giocatore_74: {
          nome:'Marco',
          muero:8,
          ruolo:'playmaker'
        },
        giocatore_65: {
          nome:'Alessandro',
          muero:4,
          ruolo:'guardia'
        }
    },
    squadra_B: {
        giocatore_87: {
          nome:'Carlo',
          muero:5,
          ruolo:'playmaker'
        },
        giocatore_98: {
          nome:'Alessio',
          muero:4,
          ruolo:'ala piccola'
        }
    }
}; 

_.each(partita, function(partito, key,list) {
  _.each(partito, function(gio) {
    console.log(gio.nome)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```